# Supposedly ambiguous explicit conversion operator in MSVC, not in gcc or clang

Tags: c++, string, c++17, implicit-conversion

Consider the following class that implements a user-conversion to `std::string` and `const char*`:

```cpp
class String {
public:
    String(std::string_view s) : str{s} {}
    operator std::string() const {
        return str;
    }
    operator const char*() const {
        return str.c_str();
    }
private:
    std::string str;
};


int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<String, std::string>);
    String s("Hello World");
    auto x = static_cast<std::string>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC tells me that static_casting to `std::string` is ambiguous, while clang and gcc do not: https://godbolt.org/z/7de5YvTno

```
<source>(20): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'String' to 'std::string'
<source>(20): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
Compiler returned: 2
```

Which compiler is right?

As a follow-up question: I can fix the ambiguity by marking the conversion operations explicit. But then `std::is_convertible_v<String, std::string>` returns `false`. Is there a type trait `is_explicitly_convertible` or `is_static_castible` or similar?

PS: I know the simplest *and* cleanest solution would be to have a non-copying conversion operator to `const std::string&`, but I still want to understand why MSVC rejects the code.

Comment: fyi - adding a `const` fixes the compilation - no idea why - `operator const std::string() const` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/c31MhhYbW

Comment: It should be `operator const std::string&() const`

Comment: @273K Do you mean the code style would be better (If yes, I agree) or the code in the provided example is invalid C++? If the latter is true, could you provide an explanation of what is wrong with it?

Comment: W/o a string copy is better.

Comment: I am guessing it's a bug. I opened an issue here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-claims-implicit-conversion-to-be-am/10283781

Comment: Please include the error message in your question. Links to other sites may be unstable.

Answer (score 3):

This is [CWG2327](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2327.html).

As written, the direct-initialization specified for `static_cast` strictly considers **constructors** for `std::string`, and the `String` argument requires incomparable user-defined conversions to satisfy either the move constructor or the converting constructor from `const char*`.  Note that, regardless of the set of conversion functions available, a constructor must be called, which is the missed **copy elision** mentioned in the issue.

The intent is that constructors and conversion functions are **simultaneously** considered for the actual initialization of `x`.  This is a bit unusual in that member functions of `std::string` and `String` are in the same overload set, but it resolves the ambiguity because calling `operator std::string` is an exact match for the (implied object) argument, and it allows `x` to **be** the return value from that function in the ordinary C++17 sense.

MSVC is implementing the standard as written, while GCC and Clang are implementing (something like) the intended resolution.

(`std::is_constructible` is more or less the direct-initialization trait you also asked about.)

Comment: Isn't the CWG talking about copy elision?  How does that effect MSVS picking up an ambiguity?

Comment: Is it really? In contrast to my example the code snippet from the defect report compiles fine in all compilers, I suppose just without copy elision (I haven't checked).

Comment: @joergbrech MSVC will elide the copy/move when possible, but Clang and GCC go further in also changing the overload resolution rules.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still having trouble understanding this. Which overload resolution rules are changed by clang and gcc?

Comment: @joergbrech: I expanded the answer, although Brian Bi is the real expert here!

Comment: Ok thanks, so I think it's dawning on me now. But this also implies an inconsistency in MSVC with the behavior of `std::is_convertible` right? `std::is_convertible_v<String, std::string` is true on all compilers.

Comment: Also, why does it compile if we change the conversion to return either `std::string const` or `std::string const&`? Wouldn't this be the same ambiguity with the copy constructor and converting constructor for `char const*`?